# find the equation of a sphere with endpoints A and B where B is the point of tangency of the sphere and the plane

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, spherical-geometry, spheres

Find the equation of a sphere with a diameter that has endpoints $A(1, 8, −2)$ and $B$, where $B$ is the point of tangency of the sphere with the plane $−9x +6y + 2z = 2$.

Now i know that i can get the distance of the point to the plane by $\frac{|-9(1)+6(8)+2(2)-2|}{\sqrt{81+36+4}}$ then dividing it by $2$ to get the radius. my problem then is finding the center of the sphere. can anybody help me???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. The direction perpendicular to a plane with an equation like 
$$
ax  + by + cz = d
$$
is always $(a, b, c)$. That means that in your case, this direction is $(-9, 6, 2)$. So the ray from $A$ towards that plane consists of point of the form
$$
(x, y, z) = (1, 8, -2) + t (-9, 6, 2) = (1 - 9t, 8-6t, -2+2t)
$$
for any positive value of $t$.

Exactly ONE of these will lie on the plane, i.e., if you plug 
$$
(x, y, z) = (1 - 9t, 8-6t, -2+2t)
$$
into the plane equation 
$$
-9x + 6y + 2z = 2
$$
and solve for $t$, you'll get just one answer. Suppose it's $t = 5$. Then your point $B$
is just
$$
(1 - 9\cdot 5, 8-6\cdot 5, -2+2 \cdot 5).
$$
And the sphere's center is just the average of $A$ and $B$.

Now...can you work out those steps for yourself?

Comment: woah. amazing. thanks :))

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be $(1,8,-2)-1.5\cdot(-9,6,2)/11$, since the radius equals $3$ and the plane's normal vector points towards $A$?

Comment: Yes...but that requires knowing about unit vectors, etc., and OP doesn't seem to quite be at that point.

Comment: ?????????? haha

Comment: Sorry...I didn't mean to be rude or insulting, @Madison; I was merely trying to explain why I'd given all the detail that I did in my answer. For the future, it's great if you can give context, as in "I'm taking a pre-calc class and can't do this problem" or "I'm doing research in differential geometry, and I'm stuck on this thing which seems as if it ought to be simple." It'll save people like me a lot of typing if you already know more advanced concepts...which we can only guess about if you don't tell us.